# SSR with Angular and Module Federation

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, webpack-module-federation

I am using angular version 13.1.0 and I have enabled SSR through `ng add @nguniversal/common`. After adding this configuration I add module federation with `ng add @angular-architects/module-federation@14.0.1`. This adds extra configuration to do SSR, one of them is to modify **CustomResourceLoader** from `@nguniversal/common` in the `server.ts` file.

```
import { CustomResourceLoader } from '@nguniversal/common/clover/server/src/custom-resource-loader'; // Not found CustomResourceLoader
import { createFetch } from '@angular-architects/module-federation/nguniversal';

...

// Without mappings, remotes are loaded via HTTP
const mappings = {
};

// Monkey Patching Angular Universal for Module Federation
CustomResourceLoader.prototype.fetch = createFetch(mappings);
```

The new version of `@nguniversal/common@13.0.2` does not export the CustomResourceLoader so it cannot be modified for module federation use..

Do you know of a way to make `@nguniversal/common` compatible with module federation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment (February 2022) the github of module federation mentions this:

> "because of a bug in Angular Universal 13, SSR is currently not
> supported for Angular 13. However, we are monitoring this situation
> and providing a solution as soon as these issues are fixed."

https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/migration-guide.md